# How to solve Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

```js
let state = true

function start() {

  setTimeOut(() => {

    if (state == true) {

      console.log("switch bulb on");

      state = false
    } else {
      console.log("switch bulb off");
      state = true
    }
    start()
  }, 3000);

  start()
}
start() //calling the main function outside the setTimeOut func
```

The intention of the above code was trying to change the state of a styled bulb in css using the in build js setTimeout function to on or off depending on the state of the define global variable.

- **Pseudocode**
- set state to true
- if state is true
- log: bulb on
- delay()
- log: bulb off

doing this continuously as long as the state is true.

Comment: `start()` calls `start()` which calls `start()` which calls `start()` which calls `start()`...

Comment: As noted above you have an endless recursion.

Comment: `setTimeOut` or `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you have infinite recursion. Simply remove the second `start()` which is inside the function, and that should solve the issue:

```
let state = true;
function start() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (state == true) {`enter code here`
            console.log("state is on");
            state = false
        } else {
            console.log("state is off");
            state = true
        }
        start()
    }, 3000);

    // start() <-- removed
}

start()
```